# How can I make all tables and data tables focusable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a web application that uses a combination of regular table and data tables across many pages and I am looking to make them focusable so that the pages are more friendly to screen readers. I found that manually setting the table elements tab index to 0 accomplished this task, but I'm looking for a way more efficient way to do this without setting tab index manually on every single table.

Comment: By focusable, do you mean that you want to have a border for the table on click?

Comment: @MisterCal I'm trying to tab through the page and get the border that way. They're already focusable via clicking. I'm trying to make the page more friendly to blind people though.

Comment: The only way to manipulate the order of tab is through setting the tab index. You can create a single javascript loop function that iterates through each table element like @Eliseo listed below. But you would probably want a linear order instead of setting them all to 0. So you would wan't to increment by 1 as a part of the loop function.

Comment: @MisterCal I want the table elements in the logical navigation flow. I don't see the benefit of manually setting their tab index. I'm trying to implement Eliseo's solution but it's not working.

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of tab from what is is currently doing, the only way to do it is so set tab index to get different behavior. Can you post your implementation so I can see the problem?

Comment: @MisterCal I understand that, meant that I don't see the benefit of a tab index of anything other than 0. I'll try to update the post with more informartion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find for all tables and add attribute

```html
<script>
document
    .querySelectorAll('table')
    .forEach(
        table => table.setAttribute('tabindex', '0')
    )
</script>
```

put that script at bottom of  `body`